# Ubuntu 12.04 dell inspiron 1440 wireless network does not work with wireless networkdisconnected messages

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my laptop dell inspiron 1440. Wired connection works fine. But wireless connection does not work. I installed the driver. I can see my home wireless net work and configured with password. but after configuring it, it keep saying wireless network disconnected. I removed wired connection and internet does not work with wireless even though I see my network. This is what I did after going through previous questions.

lspci -nn to check what driver I need. The output is;
Broacom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315 (rev 01)

As per recommendation I did this;

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl

Assuming the wireless switch is on, your wireless should now be working; check:

rfkill list all

But I still get this message "wireless network disconnected" and wireless connection does not work. I ran software updates to make sure I am current before doing the above.

I spent lot of time on this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your device also has another driver available that sometimes works better. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer
```

Detach the ethernet, reboot and let us know how it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same wireless card and this is the procedure I go through on a new install to get my wireless working:

```
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer b43-fwcutter
```

then with your favorite text editor open up the file **blacklist.conf** in the **/etc/modprobe.d/** directory and comment out 'blacklist bcm43xx' by putting a # in front of the text. Should look something like this:

```
# replaced by b43 and ssb.
#blacklist bcm43xx
```

You will probably need to restart your computer for the wireless to register. hope that helps!